# Java: xml to singleton (using maven & jaxb)

Tags: java, xml, maven, xsd, jaxb

I want to do such thing completely automatically by maven.
I have a .xml file with some data. There is some references by ids from one object in this xml to another, and so on. I don't have .xsd of this .xml.

I need exactly two things:
1) Compile this xml to Java classes. 
2) Creating one Singleton class named by this .xml name and containing all .xml data relative the inner .xml structure.

For example, my .xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MyBigSinletonWithAllData>
    <Cars>
        <Car id="1" speed = "5"/>
        <Car id="2" speed = "3"/>       
    </Cars> 
</MyBigSinletonWithAllData>
```

And I want to get somehting like this, as automatic output:

```
class MyBigSinletonWithAllData {
    List<Cars> cars;
}

class Car {
    double speed;
}

class MyBigSinletonWithAllDataSingleton {

    MyBigSinletonWithAllData INSTANCE = new MyBigSinletonWithAllData(); 
    /* And here we read an INSTANCE from our .xml file */
}
```

So, my question is how to do this fully automatically by Maven?
I don't want to code manually the "MyBigSinletonWithAllDataSingleton", I just want to get it already generated for me, so I need only to write code line like this:

```
MyBigSinletonWithAllDataSingleton.INSTANCE
```

to get full access to all data that written in relative .xml file.

For now I use "maven-jaxb2-plugin" to generate Java classes from .xsd; But I also need a tool that do .xsd from .xml, and tool that create automatically read/write operations to singleton.

Answer (score 0):

In Java SOAP based webservices there are different implementation like apache axis and apche cxf. In that implementations we have tools which we will run or simply we will pass the XML file to that tool so corresponding binding classes will be generated.

Please look into their code so that it will helps you.
or may be some different tools also will be there(google it).

And yes you can convert xml to xsd file.
Go through the link

[Conver XML to XSD](http://xmlgrid.net/xml2xsd.html)